# React native custom component

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use the ios toolbar and import it into a component to use for react native. I don't understand where I went wrong. I am getting the error "uknown module Toolkit.ios.js" when I use `var Tool = require('toolkit.ios.js');`

The file is there. What Am I missing here?
I was trying to follow this tutorial here but with the toolbar component
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#content

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@import UIKit;

#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCTToolBar : RCTViewManager
@end

@implementation RCTToolBar


RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
}

@end
```

// MapView.js

```
var React = require('react-native');
var { requireNativeComponent } = React;

// requireNativeComponent automatically resolves this to "RCTMapManager"

class ToolBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RCTToolBar />;
  }
}

module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RCTToolBar', ToolBar);
```

edit: messed up on copy and pasting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require the file with a relative path, something like: `var Tool = require('./path/to/componenttoolkit')`

Also, you don't need to have `ios.js` in your require statements, the packager is smart enough to know what your component is and also this will help eventually when you want to have cross platform components.

Comment: That was one part of the issue, another was because I was following the example and named the files RCTMapManager.m, they already exist so I was getting duplicate references. Thanks for the input.